# file://data/user/0/pe.com.mobilebanking/app_PDFDir/archivo.pdf exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

Tags: android, pdf, studio

el error: file://data/user/0/pe.com.mobilebanking/app_PDFDir/archivo.pdf exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

este es mi codigo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el còdigo como texto por favor ya que no es visible para toda la comunidad, revisa [ask], saludos

Answer (score 0):

El error está a la hora de añdir el archivo pdf al intent. Si lo haces utlizando Uri.parse() debes solo añadir la dirección local del archvio, quedaría así:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(PATH));
```

Pero te recomiendo utilizar el método fromFile de la clase Uri, porque no todas las aplicaciones son capaces de localizar el archivo con el método parse(). Entonces el código quedaría así:

```
try {
    String PATH = getIntent().getStringExtra("PATH_PDF");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    File pdfFile = new File(PATH);
    if (pdfFile.exists()) {
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pdfFile));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Compartir Estado Cuenta"));
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No olvides añadir el permiso de lectura y escritura en el Manifest y pedirlo en tiempo de ejecución en el caso que estés utilizando SDK > 23.

Comment: Esto que comentas no tiene que ver con si un mètodo localiza o no el archivo: "te recomiendo utilizar el método fromFile de la clase Uri, porque no todas las aplicaciones son capaces de localizar el archivo con el método parse()." esto depende de la versiòn de API usada.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración compañero, había intentado usar Uri.parse () pero me indicaba error y cuando cambie a Uri.fromFile () ya no, pero no sabia que era por la versión de API.